# Define Bootstrap columns with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to define 4 different outputs. In my HTML I want to say how many columns I would like to show, then in JavaScript I would run this code if there are 4 columns:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Run this code if there are 3 columns:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Run this code if there 2 columns:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Run this code if there is 1 column:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

Is there a way doing this with AngularJS?

Comment: Can simply do it on the template side and use ng-if with something like `ng-if="colCount == 2"` and so on.

Comment: How are you deciding the number of columns? Dont know angular but run a loop and set the `col-md-` class to **12/no of columns**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this:

NG:

```
$scope.number = 4;//your column count 
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number) track by $index" class="col-sm-{{12/number}}">
     <h1>Content</h1>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ck8vb1s/1/